# Как исправить ошибку pafy " self._dislikes = self._ydl_info['dislike_count'] KeyError: 'dislike_count'"

Tags: python-3.x

> File "C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\Users\Smart\Desktop\python\project upload_videos_youtube\tube.py", line 37, in press
> video = pafy.new(url)
> File "C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\pafy.py", line 124, in new
> return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts=ydl_opts)
> File "C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py", line 31, in **init**
> super(YtdlPafy, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_shared.py", line 97, in **init**
> self._fetch_basic()
> File "C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py", line 54, in _fetch_basic
> self._dislikes = self._ydl_info['dislike_count']
> KeyError: 'dislike_count'

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с этой проблемой и хочу рассказать как ее исправить!
Во первых из-за чего эта ошибка происходит?
Эта ошибка из-за небольшого обновления ютуб.
Очевидно библиотека не может посчитать кол-во дизлайков в файле backend_youtube_dl.py а именно в 54 строке.
Просто откроем cmd и введем команду C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py 
*У вас путь к файлу может отличаться!!!

Откроется файл в редакторе, и сделайте строку 54, комментарием(добавив перед этой строкой знак #), сохраните файл и закройте.
Теперь ошибки нет, но кол-во дизлайков вы не сможете получить.